# How does multiple inheritance and concatenate inheritance work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I was reading some articles on Javascript's prototypal inheritance. I understood that inheritance can be done via "Delegation" in which the properties to be inherited are defined on the object's prototype chain.

Next it mentioned Concatenative Inheritance. It mentioned that the properties that are inherited are copied to the object. There were some examples mentioned in the article, but there were based on ES6. I was wondering if someone could provide some examples on how Concatenative inheritence works in Javascript for the previous standards.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=concatenative+inheritance+javascript&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&oq=Concatenative+Inheritance+javas&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.1861j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: There is no multiple inheritance with delegation in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, you can add any properties and/or methods to an existing object.

```js
function addHello(obj){
    obj.someProperty = 
    obj.sayHello = function(){
       console.log("Hello");
    }
}

var myObj = {
    foo: "bar"
};

addHello(myObj);

myObj.sayHello();
```

Comment: That's a mixin, not exactly concatenative inheritance.

Comment: @Bergi thats kind of what I thought they were asking.

Comment: Hm, I'd define concatenative inheritance as using multiple mixins in another mixin or a factory function (if I'm not confusing that with parasitic inheritance). So what I'm missing in your answer is the sub"class".